# Wamp, External IP, Forbidden

Tags: wampserver

For start i am using windows 7 Ultimate Sp1 x64, 
The problem: cant access my wamp server through the my external IP, 
Until today i was using:

**WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & PHP 5.4) 2.2E**

**Apache 2.2.22** – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.4.3 XDebug 2.1.2 XDC 1.5 PhpMyadmin 3.4.10.1 SQLBuddy 1.3.3 webGrind 1.0

At this version all was great all worked fine i was able to access the localhost/127.0.0.1 my Internal/External IP, 
Until i replaced this version to this one:

**WAMPSERVER (64 BITS & APACHE 2.4) 2.2E**

**Apache 2.4.2** – Mysql 5.5.24 – PHP 5.4.3 XDebug 2.1.2 XDC 1.5 PhpMyadmin 3.4.10.1 SQLBuddy 1.3.3 webGrind 1.0

If you can see the Apache version is not the same, so again with this version i cant access my external IP,

What i have done:

Port 80 is open i didnt change the port, 
The firewall allow the HTTP Server and Wamp(Even it allow i turned off the firewall just to be sure),

I did tested this [Link](http://dnhome.wordpress.com/2011/10/14/apache-403-forbidden-you-dont-have-permission-to-access-on-this-server/)

After i follow the guide at the link i could access with my adress but not with my IP, The problem is with the new apache version so if anyone saw this problem before with this new version (**Apache 2.4.2**) and can please help me i will be very thankful, Thank you all and have a nice day.

Comment: I have the same problem, how you fix it?

Comment: http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,89983,89998#msg-89998 Good Luck.